# last n elements of an array

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to write a function that will print out the last 3 elements of $PWD, with a '...' beforehand if there are more than 3 elements.

e.g.

```
/home/nornagon/src             --> ~/src
/home/nornagon/src/foo/bar/baz --> ...foo/bar/baz
```

This is my code so far, but `$foo[-3,-1]` doesn't work if the array has too few elements in it.

```
function custom_pwd() {
  d=${PWD/#$HOME/\~}
  d=(${(s:/:)d})
  echo $d[-4,-1]
}
```

Comment: I would probably want to know the first one or two elements as well.

Answer (score 2):

The zsh already has some nifty prompt processing available with print's -P option. This should do the trick:

```
custom_pwd() {
   d=$(print -P '%3~')
   case $d in
      ('~'*|/*) echo "$d";;
      (*)       echo "...$d"
   esac
}
```

See `man zshmisc`, section "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES" for the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, though it's not terribly elegant:

```
function custom_pwd() {
  local d slash
  d=${PWD/#$HOME/\~}
  case $d in
    /*) slash=/ ;;
    *) slash= ;;
  esac
  d=(${(s:/:)d})
  d[1]=$slash$d[1]
  num=$#d
  ellipsis=
  if (( num > 3 )); then num=3; ellipsis='…'; fi
  echo $ellipsis${(j./.)d[-$num,-1]}
}
```